# Gradient text color

Tags: css, generator, gradient, linear-gradients

Is there a generator , or an easy way to generate text like [this](http://patorjk.com/text-color-fader/) but without having to define *every* letter

So something like this:

```css
.rainbow {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
  background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
  color:transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<span class="rainbow">Rainbow text</span>
```

But not with *rainbow* colors but generate with other colors (for example white to grey/light blue gradient etc) I can't find an easy solution for this. Any solutions?

Comment: There are many websites which offer the same like http://www.cssmatic.com/

Comment: What's the problem there? Change the gradient as you wish. If you are asking about tools/generators (which I think you are) then your question will get closed as off-topic/opinion based.

Comment: That only applies to the _background_ not the text color itself :|

Comment: I'm trying to get to know how to get the same effect as the _rainbow text_ sample but with other colors @Harry not asking for a generator _perse_ a solution on how to simply set the colors myself / how the _rainbow_ sample works would be a great help aswell.

Comment: I'd love to know how it works. Because the given answer uses a different a approach (which works, but I still love to know) @Harry

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I don't exactly know how the *stop* stuff works.
But I've got a *gradient text* example. Maybe this will help you out!

_you can also add more colors to the gradient if you want or just select other colors from the [color generator](http://html-color-codes.info/)

```css
.rainbow2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #E0F8F7, #585858, #fff);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}

.rainbow {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f22, #f2f, #22f, #2ff, #2f2, #ff2);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<span class="rainbow">Rainbow text</span>
<br />
<span class="rainbow2">No rainbow text</span>
```

Comment: but the -webkit-background-clip: text; property is not supported on IE11, any alternative?

Comment: I can't seems to work it properly with `text-shadow`, since `background-image`'s `z-index` always below the the `text-shadow`. Any idea?

Comment: will it work in IE11, No.
Can you update with IE11 support?.

Answer (score 16):

The way this effect works is very simple. The element is given a background which is the gradient. It goes from one color to another depending on the colors and color-stop percentages given for it.

For example, in rainbow text sample (note that I've converted the gradient into the standard syntax):

- The gradient starts at color `#f22` at `0%` (that is the left edge of the element). First color is always assumed to start at `0%` even though the percentage is not mentioned explicitly.
- Between `0%` to `14.25%`, the color changes from `#f22` to `#f2f` gradually. The percenatge is set at `14.25` because there are seven color changes and we are looking for equal splits.
- At `14.25%` (of the container's size), the color will exactly be `#f2f` as per the gradient specified.
- Similarly the colors change from one to another depending on the bands specified by color stop percentages. Each band should be a step of `14.25%`.

So, we end up getting a gradient like in the below snippet. Now this alone would mean the background applies to the entire element and not just the text.

```css
.rainbow {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f22, #f2f 14.25%, #22f 28.5%, #2ff 42.75%, #2f2 57%, #2f2 71.25%, #ff2 85.5%, #f22);
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<span class="rainbow">Rainbow text</span>
```

Since, the gradient needs to be applied only to the text and not to the element on the whole, we need to instruct the browser to clip the background from the areas outside the text. This is done by setting `background-clip: text`.

(*Note that the `background-clip: text` is an experimental property and is not supported widely.*)

---

Now if you want the text to have a simple 3 color gradient (that is, say from red - orange - brown), we just need to change the linear-gradient specification as follows:

- First parameter is the direction of the gradient. If the color should be red at left side and brown at the right side then use the direction as `to right`. If it should be red at right and brown at left then give the direction as `to left`.
- Next step is to define the colors of the gradient. Since our gradient should start as red on the left side, just specify `red` as the first color (percentage is assumed to be 0%).
- Now, since we have two color changes (red - orange and orange - brown), the percentages must be set as 100 / 2 for equal splits. If equal splits are not required, we can assign the percentages as we wish.
- So at `50%` the color should be `orange` and then the final color would be `brown`. The position of the final color is always assumed to be at 100%.

Thus the gradient's specification should read as follows:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange 50%, brown).
```

If we form the gradients using the above mentioned method and apply them to the element, we can get the required effect.

```css
.red-orange-brown {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange 50%, brown);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
.green-yellowgreen-yellow-gold {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, green, yellowgreen 33%, yellow 66%, gold);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<span class="red-orange-brown">Red to Orange to Brown</span>

<br>

<span class="green-yellowgreen-yellow-gold">Green to Yellow-green to Yellow to Gold</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve that effect using a combination of CSS [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) and [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode).

**HTML**

```
<p>
    Enter your message here... 
    To be or not to be, 
    that is the question...
    maybe, I think, 
    I'm not sure
    wait, you're still reading this?
    Type a good message already!
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

p::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple);
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

What this does is add a linear gradient on the paragraph's `::after` pseudo-element and make it cover the whole paragraph element. But with `mix-blend-mode: screen`, the gradient will only show on parts where there is text.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hvpc7xz7/) to show this at work. Just modify the `linear-gradient` values to achieve what you want.

Comment: This looks promising. Except for the background _behind_ the text is also fading with it. Apart from that easy and nice solution! +1

Comment: @AngelofDemons oh, I was assuming that the background will just be white. `mix-blend-mode` blends the element with all the other elements behind it, not just the text, so if the paragraph also has a background, the rainbow colors will also blend with them. I know, it sucks :(

Comment: It doesn't suck I love the approach its easy and usefull. I tried using it [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37832318/6338065) way.

Comment: Not supported by Edge (nor IE 10/11) and doesn't work in Chrome for me (although it works in Firefox) EDIT: it does work in chrome, if the parent `p` has `background-color: white;`

Answer (score 3):

**Example of CSS Text Gradient**

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#E605C1 0%,#3B113B 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#E605C1 0%,#3B113B 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#E605C1 0%,#3B113B 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#E605C1 0%,#3B113B 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(top,#E605C1 0%,#3B113B 100%);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
position:relative;
display:inline-block; /*required*/
```

**Online generator**
[textgradient.com](http://www.textgradient.com)

Answer (score 2):

```css
body{ background:#3F5261; text-align:center; font-family:Arial; } 

h1 {
  font-size:3em;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, gold, white);
  background: linear-gradient(top, gold, white);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

  position:relative;
  margin:0;
  z-index:1;

}

div{ display:inline-block; position:relative; }
div::before{ 
   content:attr(data-title); 
   font-size:3em;
   font-weight:bold;
   position:absolute;
   top:0; left:0;
   z-index:-1;
   color:black;
   z-index:1;
   filter:blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div data-title='SOME TITLE'>
  <h1>SOME TITLE</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
  .gradient_text_class{
      font-size: 72px;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffff00 0%, #0000FF 30%);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffff00 0%, #0000FF 30%);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
```

```html
<div class="gradient_text_class">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400);

body {
  background: #222;
}

h1 {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab";
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 7em;
  background: linear-gradient(330deg, #e05252 0%, #99e052 25%, #52e0e0 50%, #9952e0 75%, #e05252 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<h1>beautiful</h1>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Comment: will it work in IE11, No.
Can you update with IE11 support?.